# sqlalchemy postgresql function calls within transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write tests for my PostgreSQL functions.  I'm having trouble understanding why my PostgreSQL functions return nothing.

```
def test_sql_func_get_loc_eft_draft_one(session):
    test_passed = True

    # Build up the test environment
    trans = session.begin()

    # Add a dummy location record
    add_dummy_location(session)

    # Add a dummy membership record
    add_one_dummy_member(session)

    # Print the membership record we just wrote
    req_query = session.query(models.Membership).\
        filter(models.Membership.home_club == 9999).first()
    print(req_query)

    # Run the test with one record
    t1 = session.query(func.get_dues(9999, '1/1/2014', '1/1/2016')).first()
    print(t1)
    try:
        assert t1[0] == 10.00

    except:
        test_passed = False

    # Break down the test environment
    trans.rollback()

    assert test_passed
```

When I print the membership record that I wrote, it displays correctly, with 10.00 in the dues field.  When I try to use the function to retrieve the dues, zero comes back, and the test fails.  Can I not use PostgreSQL function calls within Transactions?

Comment: you can use functions within transactions. What is the definition of `get_dues`?

Comment: I found my error.  Adding a new member should fire a trigger to create a member history record, but that was never being created because it wasn't a deferred constraint trigger.

Comment: Or rather, it WAS a deferred constraint trigger.